# pdf not downloading properly

Tags: httprequest, httpresponse, blob.topdf

I have these lines of code:

```
    public String getCoverPdf()
    {
        if(!String.isBlank(pdfLink))
        {
            Http h = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setMethod('GET');
            HttpResponse res; 
            String redirect = pdfLink;
            do
            {
                system.debug('### redirect: ' + redirect);
                req.setEndpoint(redirect);
                res = h.send(req);
                redirect = res.getHeader('Location');
                system.debug('### response status: ' + res.getStatusCode() + ' ' + res.getStatus());
            }
            while(302 == res.getStatusCode());

            system.debug('### ViewCoverLink_Controller.getCoverPdf: ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(res.getBodyAsBlob()));
            return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(res.getBodyAsBlob());
        }
    }
```

with the following visualforce page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" controller="ViewCoverLink_Controller">
    <iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{!getCoverPdf}" style="border: 0; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%"/>    
</apex:page>
```

the browser shows an error like "unable to load pdf document". The weird thing is that if read the log and i copy the url returned from the last "system.debug('### redirect: ' + redirect)" in my browser's address bar the pdf is showed properly . Moreover if i set any other endpoint with a pdf the whole code works fine. Is there any reason for this behavior?

Comment: your `getCoverPdf` is private is it?

Comment: I didn't understand clearly what you said about the last url... What is that last URL? And For the Apex Method you are specifying as private which is accessible only to the Apex Class... Why so?

Comment: @highfive just a typo it was public; subhash sorry :) edited, hope it's more clear

Comment: did you try giving only the CoverPdf in the src? like iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{!CoverPdf}"..............

Comment: @subhash thanks, but the result is the same "failed to load pdf document"

Comment: Which browser you are using? It won't work in IE.... In Mozilla and Chrome, It is working fine for me... It is asking me to save file and if i open saved file, it is showing my text...

Comment: i tried with chrome and firefox.... i don't think it's relevant because if i copypaste the endpoint url in the browser's address bar i can see the pdf, meanwhile if i set another endpoint that does not have to be redirect the code works...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41200/discussion-between-subhash-and-joulinrouge).